# How to access the docker container service running in same instance with instanceip and container-port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus

Here is the overview of the problem I am facing.

Suppose I have a instance **x.x.x.x** and where I am running the following services.

1. Docker container for prometheus running in 9090
2. Docker container for alertmanager running in 9093

The services are running well I can access the service using the instance url followed by their IP.

**Problem:**

My service 1 (Prometheus) needs to access service2 (alertmanager) with the **hosturl:ip** ie X.X.X.X:9090 is when trying to access X.X.X.X:9093 it is not being possible Throwing the following errors.

**How I tested:**
Entered inside service1 container and tried telneting it

```
telnet: can't connect to remote host (X.X.X.X): No route to host
```

I am not sure but have come to realize this is due to the docker firewall issues. if so than What can be done or what is the possible solutions for the scenario. How do I make the service2 accessible to service1 with the **< hostIP :port >**

**docker ps  result**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
0ac39e87eb27        prom/alertmanager             "/bin/alertmanager --"   53 minutes ago      Up 53 minutes       0.0.0.0:9093->9093/tcp              alertmanager_1
25a7de42d57f        prom/prometheus               "/bin/prometheus --co"   53 minutes ago      Up 53 minutes       0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp
prometheus
```

***NOTE:***
I am running the services using the docker-compose. So the docker-compose solutions would be more appreciated

Comment: did you expose your port?

Comment: Can you update question with `docker ps`

Comment: yes ports are exposed and I can publicly access both of them @aerokite

Comment: Since both ports are working fine explicitly & you are using a compose, can't you give service name defined in compose to prometheus instead of host IP? 
Currently, it does seems like a firewall issue.

Comment: giving the service name is not solving the issue. Ok than how to fix a firewall issue. How to disable it . It may not be wise idea to disable but how can I do that for now

Comment: Your `docker ps` shows prometheus on port 9090 and shows alertmanager on port 9093, I don’t see any 8080 port open…

Comment: you should provide your docker-compose.yml or how you start your containers. Both apps can communicate with each other even though you dont EXPOSE the port so it could stay more secure...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not linking your services. The proper solution would be to run both services from the same docker-compose file and link them toegether. Than you can use the docker-compose service name to access the Alertmanager in the other container from Prometheus.